# Authenticating to IBM Object Storage with OpenStack4j

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, object-storage, openstack4j

I'm having a hard time authenticating to the Object Storage Service in IBM Cloud from an external Java application using the OpenStack4j library (version 3.1.0). Here's how I'm trying:

```
Identifier domainIdentifier = Identifier.byName("DOMAIN");
Identifier projectIdentifier= Identifier.byName("PROJECT");

OSClient.OSClientV3 os = OSFactory.builderV3()
  .endpoint("https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v3")
  .credentials("USER", "PASS")
  .scopeToProject(projectIdentifier, domainIdentifier)
  .authenticate();
```

References:

https://github.com/acloudfan/IBM-Object-Storage-Sample/

https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bluemix-objectstorage-sample-liberty

The problem seems to be that I can't figure out where to get the **DOMAIN** and **PROJECT** information mentioned above, and perhaps the endpoint. The documentation says to obtain them from the **Object Storage** page under **Service Credentials** and **View Credentials**. I do see a JSON output with the following fields:

```
{
  "apikey": "...",
  "endpoints": "...",
  "iam_apikey_description": "...",
  "iam_apikey_name": "...",
  "iam_role_crn": "...",
  "iam_serviceid_crn": "...",
  "resource_instance_id": "..."
}
```

None of which seem to relate to domain or project information, at least by name. I even created a separate Web App with an Object Storage Connector, and tried to obtain the information from the Environment Variables page, as some of the documentation suggested, but with no luck.

What I ultimately want to achieve is to be able to ingest files to a container I created, and use the data & analytics services on top (Data Science Experience).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the confusion is that there are (or used to be) two different Object Storage services on Bluemix (**Object Storage** and **Cloud Object Storage**). The bluemix-mobile-services SDK is written for the **Object Storage** one rather than the service you have provisioned.

The App Service page has a starter kit which makes it pretty easy to get starter code and set up with a toolchain for a Liberty project:

[image: example of starter]

This has the domain field for the credentials. (Here is a link to the starter kits & I added the Object Storage service which injects the credentials: https://console.bluemix.net/developer/appservice/starter-kits. Or you can create a project with just the service and no code: https://console.bluemix.net/developer/appservice/create-project?services=Object-Storage)

Here is the documentation for the Java SDK for **Cloud Object Storage** if you would like to use that service instead:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries/java.html#java

---

Here is a comparison of the Object Storage services:

https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/infrastructure/object-storage-group

Comment: Ok, looks straightforward, thanks! I also updated the use case more specifically in the original post.